# How to avoid poles in contour integration?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, computational-geometry

I have two sets of points and need to construct a contour (for contour integration) that
encloses all singularities given in `points2` , but avoids enclosing singularities given `points1`, how should I implement this in Mathematica?

The purpose is for a numerical illustration of alternative approaches to defining matrix function $f(A)$. We get $f(A)$ by contour integrating $f(z)(zI-A)^{-1}dz$ around poles of $f(z)$ or around eigenvalues of $A$. Integrating around both sets of points gives 0. ([proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4682599/998))

Below is an example that works for a simple rectangular contour, however, for other choices of $f$, may need to use non-rectangular contour, and I was looking or an easy way to construct such.

```
(*** Utilities **)
ClearAll["Global`*"];
On[Assert];
SF = StringForm;
sum[mat_] := Total[mat, 2];

(* given set of imaginary points, find bounds suitable for \
ComplexPlot *)
enclosingBounds[zs_, margin_] := (
   marginVec = {-margin, margin};
   points = ReIm[zs];
   {xb, yb} = {MinMax[First /@ points] + marginVec, 
     MinMax[Last /@ points] + marginVec};
   {First[xb] + I First[yb], Last[xb] + I Last[yb]}
   );

(* Clockwise contour going around 4 points defining bounds *)
boundsToContour[bounds_] := (
   xb = First /@ (ReIm /@ bounds);
   yb = Last /@ (ReIm /@ bounds);
   contour = {{First[xb], First[yb]}, {First[xb], 
      Last[yb]}, {Last[xb], Last[yb]}, {Last[xb], 
      First[yb]}, {First[xb], First[yb]}};
   #1 + I #2 & @@@ contour
   );

(*** Main ***)
A = {{1, 4, 16}, {18, 20, 4}, {-12, -14, -7}};
d = Length[A];
ones = ConstantArray[1, {d}];
ii = DiagonalMatrix[ones];

(* Define ration function f *)
P = t |-> t + 3;
Q = t |-> 1 + t + t^2/2;
f = t |-> P[t]/Q[t];
F[A_] := MatrixFunction[f, A];

eigs = Eigenvalues[A];
roots = t /. {ToRules@Roots[Q[t] == 0, t]};

rootsG = Sequence @@ (Disk[#, .1] & /@ ReIm@roots);
eigsG = Sequence @@ (Disk[#, .1] & /@ ReIm@eigs);


doPlot[contour_, contourName_] := (
   epilog := {Magenta, rootsG, Blue, eigsG, Arrow[ReIm /@ contour]};
   g[z_] := (f[z] Inverse[z ii - A]);
   int = 
    Chop@(1/(2 Pi I)) NIntegrate @@ {g[z], {z, Sequence @@ contour}};
   zbounds = enclosingBounds[roots~Join~eigs, 2];
   ComplexPlot @@ {sum@g@z,
     {z, Sequence @@ zbounds},
     Epilog -> epilog,
     PlotLabel -> 
      SF["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \
\(``\)]\)f[z](z-A\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\()\), \(-1\)]\)=``", 
       contourName, Chop@int]
     }
   );


Print["A=", MatrixForm@A];
Print["f=", f[t]];
Print["MatrixFunction f(A): ", N@MatrixForm@F[A]]

rootContour = boundsToContour@enclosingBounds[roots, 1];
doPlot[rootContour, "poles of f"]

eigContour = Reverse@boundsToContour@enclosingBounds[eigs, 1];
doPlot[eigContour, "poles of resolvent of A"]
```

[image]

[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-dobrushkin-clean.nb)

Comment: Why do you require the path? As noted in the reply by @RolandF, can you not just use the Cauchy Residue Theorem?

Comment: Not clear at all what you're asking.  Do you mean numeric contour integration?  Do you mean a formulaic contour in terms of $z(t)$?  Do you mean for this specific set of points or a list of points in general?  Surely if it's just these points, then just a paramaterized polygonal  8 segment  key-hole contour enclosing the green points and avoiding the red points would do.

Comment: I was asking for a procedure which takes two sets of points and returns contour enclosing one set, and avoiding the other one. The motivation is for illustration like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4681797/evaluating-matrix-function-f-by-summing-over-poles-of-f) -- to show that you can compute $f(A)$ by integrating $f(z)(zI-A)^{-1}$ either clockwise around poles of $f$ or counter-clockwise around poles of $(zI-A)^{-1}$, different choice of contours should give same result @josh

Comment: Yaroslav, Ok. I understand:  Given an arbitrary set of points, create a procedure to programatically draw a (paramaterized?)  contour around an arbitrary subset of the points.  Afraid that sounds problematic for me but maybe others can address it.  If so, might it have been better to simply focus solely on this objective without mentioning the complex analysis part?

Comment: @josh this gives background https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2902848

Comment: @Yaroslav Bulatov:  The complex analysis part is elegant.  Still though I think it's simpler to just draw the contour directly on a case by case basis rather than trying what I believe is an almost impossible task of coming up with an algorithm to automatically  draw the contour for the general case.

Comment: @josh I wonder if that's what NIntegrate does internally anyway -- use the residue theorem rather than numerical integration over the contour

Comment: @Yaroslav Bulatov:  I don't think  Mathematica can use the Residue Theorem directly  to NIntegrate $f(z)$ over  a contour.  The differential of an explicit paramaterized path $z(t)$ over $\Gamma$ for example must be (manually) included in the integral in the form of  $$\int_{\Gamma} (f(z(t))\frac{dz}{dt}) dt$$.

Comment: `NIntegrate[f[z], {z, z1, z2,..., zn}]` takes a rectilinear path (in the complex plane) from `z1` to z2` to...to `zn`.

Comment: @Michael E2:  When I try the syntax:  `NIntegrate[1 + z^2, {1, 1 + I, I}]` I get an error:  "Raw object cannot be used as an iterator.  I use ver. 13.2.

Comment: @josh Looks like you forgot `z`: `NIntegrate[1 + z^2, {z, 1, 1 + I, I}]`

Comment: @Michael E2:  Thanks for quick reply.  Sorry, I can't seem to successfully prepend the $z$ to a list of complex points and then have `NIntegrate` succeed.  Can you explain how to do this given `myPoints={1,1+I,I}`?

Comment: @josh Here's what worked on the original code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4fFO.png. If you want to accumulate the path in a variable, then try `myPoints = {1, 1 + I, I};
NIntegrate[1 + z^2, Evaluate@Flatten@{z, myPoints}]`

Comment: @Michael E2:  Outstanding!  However, I had to tack-on the first point in the list at the end to make a closed contour: `Flatten@{z, blueComplexPoints, blueComplexPoints[[1]]` which gave $F(A)$ to 16 digits of accuracy (small residual imag part).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your objective is to construct separate contours around a resonable number of  arbitrary poles and eigenvalues to numerically demonstrate

$$
F(A)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\oint_{\Gamma{\large\curvearrowright}} f(z)(zI-A)^{-1}dz
$$

$$
F(A)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\oint_{\beta{\large\curvearrowleft}} f(z)(zI-A)^{-1}dz
$$
where $\beta{\large\curvearrowleft}$ is a counter clockwise contour around the poles of $f(z)$,  and $\Gamma{\large\curvearrowright}$ is a clockwise contour around the eigenvalues of A then one option is draw them free-hand using Mathematica's graphics canvas.  See below.  If that's acceptable, I can update this post with the details.

[image]

**Edit:**

Before I post the processing of the hand-drawn contours into differentiable functions that can be used with `NIntegrate`, first make sure you can successfully draw the contours and cut and paste them into variables $\texttt{poleContour}$ and $\texttt{eigenContour}$.  I have ver 13.2 which has the Graphics/Convert ToFrom Canvas menu option.  Earlier versions were easier, just select Graphics and you can choose from the menu the free-hand icon to draw the contours.  I'll describe 13.2 process.  First create the function, compute poles and eigenvalues and plot them:

```
f[z_] := (z + 3)/(1 + z + 1/2 z^2)
A = {{1, 4, 16}, {18, 20, 4}, {-12, -14, -7}};
eVals = Eigenvalues[A];
eValsG = Graphics@{PointSize[0.025], Blue, Point@ReIm@eVals};

inverseF[z_] := Inverse[z IdentityMatrix[3] - A];

poles = t /. NSolve[1 + t + 1/2 t^2, t]
polesG = Graphics@{PointSize[0.025], Red, Point@ReIm@poles};
pointPlot = 
 Show[{polesG, eValsG}, Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 10}, {-5, 5}}]

F[A_] := MatrixFunction[f, A];
F[A] // N // MatrixForm
```

Now select the graphic (get orange box around it) and from the menu choose Graphics/Convert ToFrom Canvas.  This will draw a dash line around the graphic and present a menu of graphic options below the plot.  Choose the free-hand icon.  Now using the cursor, carefully draw a contour clockwise around the blue eigenvalues and then a counter clockwise contour around the red poles being careful to try as best as you can to close up the contour at the end.  Then reselect the plot (get orange box) then double click on say the contour around the poles to get a graphics of all the points.  Then right mouse button, then from menu, choose "Copy graphics selection".  Now type in the variable $\texttt{poleContour=}$ and paste the graphics after the equal sign.

**Edit:**

Once you successfully get the graphic data in $\texttt{poleContour}$ and $\texttt{eigenContour}$, then using Michael's comment above, we can then convert the points in the hand-drawn contours to complex and then integrate $f(z)(zI-A)^{-1}$ sequentally over the list of contour points as per Michael's comment above.  Below I do the integration over the eigenvalues with the numerical results accurate to $16$ digits (small residual imag. component).  Note I have to "close" the set of points by appending the first point in `blueContourPoint` back to the integration list:

```
 blueContourPoints = 
  Flatten[Cases[eigenContour, Line[pts_] :> pts], 1];
blueComplexPoints = (#[[1]] + I #[[2]]) & /@ blueContourPoints;
blueIntResults = 
  1/(2 Pi I) NIntegrate[(f[z] inverseF[z]) , 
    Flatten@{z, blueComplexPoints, blueComplexPoints[[1]]}, 
    MaxRecursion -> 20, AccuracyGoal -> 15];
Style[blueIntResults // N // MatrixForm, 12]
F[A] // N // MatrixForm
```

Comment: Yes that would make a cool demo

Comment: @Yaroslav Bulatov:  Ok, I described how to create the contours and save to variables $\texttt{poleContour}$ and $\texttt{eigenContour}$.  Make sure you can successfully create these then I'll post how to use them to do the integrals (numerically).

Comment: Actually just a list of points suffices, as Michael E2 pointed out in comments

Comment: Getting an error when I try integrating with list of points.  Left Michael a message.  Maybe need different syntax.

Comment: @Yaroslav Bulatov:  Michael's sequential integration is much nicer.  I added a second edit above using his help.  The integration results are accurate to $F(A)$ to $16$ digits with a small residual imag component.

Comment: looks like 13.3 has new `ContourIntegrate` function that makes this easier -- https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2023/06/llm-tech-and-a-lot-more-version-13-3-of-wolfram-language-and-mathematica/

Answer (score 3):

If the integrand is holomorphic (function of z=x+Iy independent of z*= x-I Y) or antiholomorphic  (function of z*=x-Iy independent of z= x+I Y) and all the singular points are poles, you simpliy can circumvent the red points by a rectangular deviation to right-down- left.

Since the contour integral for meromorphic functions is contour independent and additive by addition of closed curves to points of the contour, you can deform the rectangular path until it encircles the poles in its inner.

Proceed until each pole is enclosed by a full circle with the circles connected via straight lines, that do not contribute, since the all are passed back and forth.

Finally you can shrink all circles to radius 0. This gives the Residuum it the points, that is the coefficient of Series[ f[z-z_k],{z,z_k} by Cauchy's theorem, because all circle integrals tend to zero  with r-> 0 except for the  simple poles 1/(z-z_k) in the series expansion, yielding  the 2 pi I, independent of the radius.

```
SetOptions[Graphics, {ImageSize -> Small, Axes -> None }];



Graphics[{
  {Thickness[0.001], Arrowheads[0.02],
   {Text["\[ClockwiseContourIntegral] # \[DifferentialD]z", {-3, 0}], 
    points1G, points2G, 
    Arrow[ReIm /@ boundsToContour@enclosingBounds[points2, .1]], 
    Arrow[{{-1.8`, -1/2}, {-0.2`, -1/2}}],
    Arrow[{{-0.2`, -1/2}, {-0.2`, 1/2}}],
    Arrow[{{-0.2`, 1/2}, {-1.8`, 1/2}}]}},
     {Arrow[{{-0.2, 0}, {0.5, 0}}], 
      Text["\[ClockwiseContourIntegral] # \[DifferentialD]z", 
         {1,  0}]}, {0.5, 0}], 
    Translate[
    {{Thickness[0.001], Arrowheads[0.06], points1G, 
    {Red, Arrowheads[0.03],
     Sequence @@ 
    (Arrow[Circle[#, .6, {-0.95 \[Pi], 0.95 \[Pi]}]] & /@ ReIm@points2)},
    {Red, Arrowheads[{0.03, -0.03}],
    Arrow[{{-1.3, 1.5}, {-0.8, 1.9}}], 
    Arrow[{{-1.3, -1.5}, {-0.8, -1.9}}],
    Arrow[{{-1., -1}, {-0.45, -1}}], Arrow[{{-1., 1}, {-0.45, 1}}],
    Arrow[{ {-0.27, 0.8}, {-0.27, -0.8}}] },
    points2G,
     Arrow[ReIm /@  boundsToContour@enclosingBounds[points2, .1]]}}, 
     {5, 0}]},  ImageSize -> 350]
```

[image]

Comment: Your direction ",you can deform the rectangular path until it encircles the poles in its inner" is not any algorithm.

Comment: Your critcal comment does not have any point. This was a graphics question. Not even the class of functions is fixed, so I chose the obvious one. Algorithms for answers of  generalized questions belong to the GPT group.

Comment: Why did this get a downvote? It is a plausible guess at an underspecified (but nonetheless interesting) question.

Comment: Indeed, this is a graphics question, I was looking for easier way to construct contour integration examples like in this [post](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2902848)